# Smartsheet Attachment through API - Simple CSV

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am struggling with the webmethod.IO workflow to send a CSV file to the Smartsheet attachment. It looks like I am missing something. Can anyone please share the Postman collection?

**File:** `C:\temp\master.csv`

**HTTP POST:** `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{SheetID}/attachments`

I tried to set the filename and path. Looks like it requires passing the memory stream and size of the file. My CSV file is only 20 KB.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used webmethods.io, but based on their [documentation](https://docs.webmethods.io/integration/connectors/connector-bundle/productivity-c/#676) it looks like the only **add attachment** operation it supports is [Attach File to *Row*](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/attachments#operation/row-attachments-attachFile).

The operation to attach a file to a row with the Smartsheet API is:

`POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/sheetId/rows/rowId/attachments`

In this endpoint, replace `sheetId` with the ID of the sheet and replace `rowId` with the ID of the row. You can determine both values by using the Smartsheet web app.

- To find Sheet ID: open the sheet and choose `Properties` from the `File` menu along the top of the screen.
- To find Row ID: click on the left-most edge of the row (to the left of the row #) to select the row, then right-click and choose `Properties` from the popup menu.

You'll need to set 4 HTTPS headers for this request:

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN HERE
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="master.csv"
Content-Length: NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_YOUR_CSV_FILE_HERE
```

In these headers, you'll need to replace `YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN HERE` with the value of your API Access Token and replace `NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_YOUR_CSV_FILE_HERE` with a numeric value that represents the number of characters (including all commas) in your csv file.

For example, here are the headers that I set when testing the operation in Postman:

[image: Postman add attachment headers]

The contents of my csv file is simply: `this,is,a,test` -- which is 14 characters in length (the value of the `Content-Length` header in my request).

Finally, you'll set the body of the request to the contents of your file (in binary format). When I tested this operation in Postman, I was able to select `binary` format for the body, and then just choose my file via the UI -- so I didn't have to manually convert my file contents to binary format -- Postman did it for me.

[image: Postman add attachment]

In Postman, I pressed the `Select file` button shown in the screenshot above and then chose the file from my machine that I wanted to upload:

[image: Postman file selected]

I imagine that webmethods.io is the same -- i.e., I'm guessing you can just choose/upload the file via the webmethods.io user interface.

---

That all said, if the webmethods.io documentation is out of date and it *does* actually support the **Attach File to *Sheet*** operation, then everything would be the same as I've described above, except that there would be no `rowId` at the end of the endpoint:

`https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/attachments`